# How to include currency with proper decimal points?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make "totalSales" and "totalCommissions" into currency format with decimal points in the right spots. ($250,000.00) Something like this

```
Console.WriteLine("Totals: " + totalSales + " " + totalCommissions);
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings -- have a look at format `"C"`

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine($"Totals: {totalSales:C} {totalCommissions:C}");
```

Here's why it works:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: Thanks for the `$` edit, was just about to add it myself. Need to go to bed.

Comment: You're setting a bad example by posting a one-line answer to a duplicate, for cheap rep :(

Comment: If I can answer in less time than it takes to find the duplicate, I usually do.

Comment: How are we supposed to rally other answerers to not promulgate dupes when the founders are doing it?